# Find rows with column equal and other different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract all rows that have same column value (wihout duplicates) and the other column value with different value.

I have problems when I'm trying to get null values since the sentence "having count (distinct)" not include null values.

My example (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=ae1db1de07f9a54171c5121b49112273) :

```
create table definition
(
   job varchar(256),
   bat varchar(256),
   descr varchar(256)
);

INSERT INTO definition (job,bat,descr)
VALUES
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTA','caracoles'),
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTA','navajas'),
   ('JOBB','SCRIPTB','navajas'),
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTC','casa'),
      ('JOBC','SCRIPTC','asombrado'),
            ('JOBC','SCRIPTC','casa'),
      ('JOBC','SCRIPTKKK','asombrado'),
      ('JOBC','SCRIPTCDSFDF','pepelu'),
      ('JOBD',NULL,'casa'),
      ('JOBD','DFDSFDSFDSF','caracoles'),
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTC','casa'),
   ('JOBA','SCRIPTC','casa'),
   ('JOBJ','SCRIPTC','casa'),
   ('JOBB','SCRIPTB','love');

SELECT DISTINCT d.*
FROM definition d
JOIN
(
SELECT job
FROM definition
GROUP BY job
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(bat)) > 1
) x
ON d.job = x.job
```

It gives me:

```
job     bat
JOBA    SCRIPTA
JOBA    SCRIPTC
JOBC    SCRIPTC
JOBC    SCRIPTCDSFDF
JOBC    SCRIPTKKK
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

I need also

```
JOBD,NULL
JOBD,DFDSFDSFDSF
```

Comment: The results do not match with the query you have written. though, can you post the db you are using

Comment: To understand better do you want all (job,bat) combinations that have at least one descr which is different from the other?

Comment: Sorry my English is very poor. I need all jobs that appears at least two times, with the different values of bat column.

Comment: thanks for the scripts and db fiddle link, it helps in crafting the solution very much

Comment: Sorry the database is posgree, I've updated the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using postgres the syntax is slightly different

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.job,d.bat
FROM definition d
JOIN
(
SELECT job
FROM definition
GROUP BY job
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(case when bat is null then '' else bat end)) > 1
) x
ON d.job = x.job
order by 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=27b4cf8e44d7a088331f70ba2b519644

Answer (score 1):

You should include NULL value as a valid value of bat field in the select sentence.

This will solve your problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*
FROM definition d
JOIN
(
SELECT job
FROM definition
GROUP BY job
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(isnull(bat, 'N/A'))) > 1
) x
ON d.job = x.job
```

Comment: Thanks Dale K for your help formatting text correctly! I'm still learning how to post properly.

Comment: Sorry not works! I forget mention that is posgresql. With posgresql not works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=36860f8367b91ce9a4a202fc2d6d650e

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `exists`:

```
select d.*
from definition d
where  exists (select 1
               from definition d2
               where d2.job = d.job and
                     d2.bat is distinct from d.bat
              );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=1e1f9ef4d8e816f178f2b26796d825f2) is a db<>fiddle.

In addition, this can make use of an index on `definition(job, bat)` and with the index should be faster than a query that has aggregation.

Comment: @absolute333 . . . I had exactly the negative of the logic you want.  I updated that answer and the SQL Fiddle.